# Postgres: "Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster" and other errors

Tags: postgresql

I run Windows and I am trying to install postgres, but I can't get it to work. During installation, I get the error:

> Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster

When I try to access the server in pgadmin or via SQL Shell, I get the error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

I have found a log in the data-folder saying:

```
2021-04-08 14:53:44.315 CEST [11088] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2021-04-08 14:53:44.321 CEST [11088] LOG:  could not listen on IPv6 address "::": Permission denied
2021-04-08 14:53:44.326 CEST [11088] LOG:  could not listen on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0": Permission denied
2021-04-08 14:53:44.327 CEST [11088] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
2021-04-08 14:53:44.328 CEST [11088] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-04-08 14:53:44.331 CEST [11088] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: @jjanes I don't know, sorry, I use a link provided by my university: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

I choose version 13.2, Windows x86-64

Comment: That is the major installer for Windows.  I've used it many times.  Did you do this from a privileged account or an ordinary account?  Can you find an installation-specific log file, like maybe `c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/installation_summary.log`

Comment: I solved it, it worked to create a new Windows user called postgres and install it as that user

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and followed different tips and tricks available on the internet but nothing worked.

I fixed that issue by following these steps:

1. First disable antivirus for an hour
2. Create a folder in either C drive or D drive and give full permission to User
3. Then again install a fresh application. If you have already installed then uninstall that and install from starting.
4. Make sure to choose that folder only at the time of installation